# Вызов метода фрагмента из активности NullPointerException. Call fragment method from activity - NullPointer

Tags: android, android-fragment

Добрый день. Возникла проблема при работе с фрагментами, а именно - не могу вызвать метод фрагмента из активности.

Код активности

```
package com.llaerto.mysecondbuylist;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ListAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public FragmentListAdd fragmentListAdd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listadd);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //здесь при нажатии на кнопку в экшен баре должен создаваться элемент (создание элемента newMyList();
        if (id == R.id.action_listadd_confirm) {
            fragmentListAdd = (FragmentListAdd) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_listadd);
            fragmentListAdd.newMyList();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
package com.llaerto.mysecondbuylist;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class FragmentListAdd extends Fragment {
    public EditText editTitleName;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listadd, null);
        editTitleName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_listadd_title);
        Button buttonConfirm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_listadd_confirm);
        buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // при клике на кнопку вызываем метод создания элемента. Здесь всё работает.
                newMyList();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    //метод создания элемента
    public void newMyList() {
        if (editTitleName.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            MainActivity.list.add(new MyList(editTitleName.getText().toString()));
            FragmentMainList.simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.warning_empty_title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```

При вызове метода `newMyList()` по кнопке во фрагменте - всё хорошо.
При попытке вызвать его через:

```
fragmentListAdd = (FragmentListAdd) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_listadd);
            fragmentListAdd.newMyList();
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
07-08 14:24:11.409  20814-20814/com.llaerto.mysecondbuylist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.llaerto.mysecondbuylist, PID: 20814
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.llaerto.mysecondbuylist.FragmentListAdd.newMyList()' on a null object reference
            at com.llaerto.mysecondbuylist.ListAddActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(ListAddActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:541)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:598)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы вызвать метод из активности.

Comment: Из того, что здесь написано, могу только посоветовать поглубже изучить тему коммуникации между фрагментом и активити. То, что вы сейчас делаете, настолько неправильно, что написать ответ нет смысла - нужно почти полностью все переделывать.

Comment: Догадывался, что делаю не правильно. Может вы заодно подскажете актуальную книгу по Android? Про фрагменты почитаю на developer.android.com, но может есть стоящая литература? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Очень хорошая книга: Брайн Харди , Билл Филипс - Программирование под Android - 2014

Comment: Из бесплатного и хорошего в ру нете startandroid.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FragmentManager возвращает тебе Null.

Так должно сработать.

```
FragmentListAdd fragment = new FragmentListAdd();
fragment.newMyList();
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже рабочий вариант. Правда уже заметил в чем ошибка. Перепутал R.layout.fragment_listadd с R.id.fragment_listadd, заменил и заработало.